# two Material UI v5 customised themes types are conflicting

Tags: material-ui

I am using Material UI v5 and creating a customised theme. I have two different frontend F1 and F2 and seperate theme for each frontend F1_theme and F2_theme both of them are customised using typescript via module augumentation. everything works fine if repo has one theme at a time either F1_theme or F2_theme but when repo has both theme at the time then it picks types on one theme and start validating both themes using that type.

F1-> theme.ts

```
import { TypographyOptions } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createTypography'
import { PaletteOptions, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'

import {
  AnswerOptionInterface,
  BackgroundOptionsInterface,
  BadgeInterface,
  BadgesI,
  BorderInterface,
  ButtonInterface,
  ButtonsInterface,
  CardContentI,
  CardDataI,
  CardDisplayI,
  CardInstitutionI,
  CardMiddleDisplayI,
  CheckboxInterface,
  ColoredOptionsInterface,
  CommonScale,
  ContentDividerInterface,
  CurbsideOverrideI,
  DrawerI,
  FullScreenModalI,
  GradientInterface,
  GraphsInterface,
  GreyScale,
  HighlightInterface,
  IconInterface,
  ListInterface,
  LoaderInterface,
  MenuItemI,
  ModalInterface,
  PaginationI,
  PanelI,
  PrimaryOptionInterface,
  SecondaryOptionInterface,
  SettingsModalI,
  ShadeI,
  SnackBarI,
  TableListI,
  TypographyInterface,
} from './types'

interface CurbsidePalletInterface extends PaletteOptions {
  answerOption: AnswerOptionInterface
  primary: PrimaryOptionInterface
  secondary: SecondaryOptionInterface
  common: CommonScale
  grey: GreyScale
  background: BackgroundOptionsInterface
  badge: BadgeInterface
  border: BorderInterface
  contentDivider: ContentDividerInterface
  gradient: GradientInterface
  graphs: GraphsInterface
  typography: TypographyInterface
  button: ButtonInterface
  buttons: ButtonsInterface
  highlight: HighlightInterface
  icon: IconInterface
  loader: LoaderInterface
  checkbox: CheckboxInterface
  list: ListInterface
  modal: ModalInterface
  fullscreenModal: FullScreenModalI
  settingModal: SettingsModalI
  drawer: DrawerI
  cardDisplay: CardDisplayI
  cardMiddle: CardMiddleDisplayI
  cardData: CardDataI
  cardContent: CardContentI
  cardInstitution: CardInstitutionI
  snackbar: SnackBarI
  badges: BadgesI
  menuItem: MenuItemI
  tableList: TableListI
  pagination: PaginationI
  panel: PanelI
}

interface CurbsideTypography extends TypographyOptions {
  fontFamily: string
  color: {
    red: string
    action: string
    green: string
    green2: string
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Theme {
    palette: CurbsidePalletInterface
  }

  interface TypeBackground {
    colored: ColoredOptionsInterface
  }

  interface BackgroundOptionsInterface extends TypeBackground {
    colored: ColoredOptionsInterface
  }
  interface CurbsideTypography extends TypographyOptions {
    fontFamily: string
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createTypography' {
  interface TypographyOptions {
    fontFamily: string
    color: {
      red: string
      action: string
      green: string
      green2: string
    }
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material' {
  interface Color {
    grey0: string
    grey1: string
    grey2: string
    grey3: string
    grey4: string
    grey5: string
    grey6: string
    grey7: string
    grey8: string
    grey9: string
    grey10: string
    grey11: string
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {
    palette: CurbsidePalletInterface
    typography: CurbsideTypography
    shade?: ShadeI
    overrides?: CurbsideOverrideI
  }

  interface ThemeOptions {
    shade?: ShadeI
    overrides?: CurbsideOverrideI
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    answerOption: AnswerOptionInterface
    border: BorderInterface
    badge: BadgeInterface
    contentDivider: ContentDividerInterface
    gradient: GradientInterface
    graphs: GraphsInterface
    button: ButtonInterface
    buttons: ButtonsInterface
    highlight: HighlightInterface
    icon: IconInterface
    loader: LoaderInterface
    checkbox: CheckboxInterface
    list: ListInterface
    modal: ModalInterface
    fullscreenModal: FullScreenModalI
    settingModal: SettingsModalI
    drawer: DrawerI
    cardDisplay: CardDisplayI
    cardMiddle: CardMiddleDisplayI
    cardData: CardDataI
    cardContent: CardContentI
    cardInstitution: CardInstitutionI
    snackbar: SnackBarI
    badges: BadgesI
    menuItem: MenuItemI
    tableList: TableListI
    pagination: PaginationI
    panel: PanelI
  }
}

export interface CurbsideExtendedMuiFiveTheme extends Theme {
  palette: CurbsidePalletInterface
  typography: CurbsideTypography
  shade?: ShadeI
  overrides?: CurbsideOverrideI
}
```

F1-> types.ts

```
import { TypographyOptions } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createTypography'
import { PaletteColor } from '@mui/material'
import { TypeBackground } from '@mui/material/styles/createPalette'
import { ComponentsOverrides } from '@mui/material/styles/overrides'
export interface CurbsideTypography extends TypographyOptions {
  fontFamily: string
  color: {
    red: string
    action: string
    green: string
    green2: string
  }
}

export interface GreyScale {
  grey0: string
  grey1: string
  grey2: string
  grey3: string
  grey4: string
  grey5: string
  grey6: string
  grey7: string
  grey8: string
  grey9: string
  grey10: string
  grey11: string
}

export interface CommonScale {
  white: string
  black: string
}
export interface AnswerOptionInterface {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  active: string
  tertiary: string
  border: string
  text: string
  activeText: string
}
export interface PrimaryOptionInterface extends PaletteColor {
  main: string
  contrastText: string
}
export interface SecondaryOptionInterface extends PaletteColor {
  main: string
}
export interface ColoredOptionsInterface {
  mkt: string
  action: string
  border: string
  red: string
  green: string
  purple1: string
  purple2: string
  blue1: string
  blue2: string
}
export interface BackgroundOptionsInterface extends TypeBackground {
  colored: ColoredOptionsInterface
}
export interface BadgeInterface {
  orderCounter: string
  orderCounterBG: string
  los: string
}
export interface BorderInterface {
  primary: string
  action: string
  green: string
}
export interface ContentDividerInterface {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
}
export interface GradientInterface {
  primary: string
}
interface CatInterface {
  swatch0: string
  swatch1: string
  swatch2: string
  swatch3: string
  swatch4: string
  swatch5: string
  swatch6: string
  swatch7: string
}
interface ConInterface extends CatInterface {
  swatch8: string
}
export interface GraphsInterface {
  cat: CatInterface
  con: ConInterface
}
export interface TypographyInterface {
  white: string
  grey3: string
  grey4: string
  grey5: string
  grey6: string
  grey7: string
  red: string
  warning: string
  action: string
  green: string
  green2: string
}
export interface ButtonInterface {
  action: string
}
export interface ButtonsInterface {
  black: string
  grey3: string
  grey4: string
  error: string
  warning: string
  white: string
  action: string
  gradient: string
  icon: string
}
export interface HighlightInterface {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  quinary: string
}
export interface IconInterface {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  base: string
  background: {
    primary: string
  }
  light: {
    hover: string
  }
}
export interface LoaderInterface {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
}
export interface CheckboxHover {
  background: string
  border: string
  text: string
  checkbox: string
  svg: string
}
export interface CheckboxActive {
  background: string
  borderColor: string
  text: string
  border: string
}
export interface CheckboxInterface {
  background: string
  text: string
  svg: string
  border: string
  hover: CheckboxHover
  active: CheckboxActive
}
export interface ListInterface {
  background: string
  text: string
  hover: {
    background: string
  }
}
export interface ModalInterface {
  backgroundHeader: string
  backgroundFooter: string
  primary: string
  header: string
  headerText: string
  background: {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
  }
  checkbox: {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
  }
}
export interface FullScreenModalI {
  background: string
  backgroundNavbar: string
  titleText: string
}
export interface SettingsModalI {
  backgroundMenu: string
  headerTextMenu: string
  backgroundMain: string
  titleMain: string
  headerTextMain: string
  helperTextMain: string
}
export interface DrawerI {
  backgroundMenu: string
  boxShadow: string
  iconButtonTextMenu: string
  iconButtonBackground: string
  iconButtonRightBar: string
  backgroundMain: string
  titleText: string
  active: {
    iconButtonTextMenu: string
  }
}
export interface CardDisplayI {
  background: string
}
export interface CardMiddleDisplayI {
  background: string
  boxShadow: string
}
export interface CardDataI {
  background: string
  title: string
  helperText: string
}
export interface CardContentI {
  background: string
  title: string
  helperText: string
  borderInstitutionLogo: string
}
export interface CardInstitutionI {
  background: string
  title: string
  helperText: string
  borderInstitutionLogo: string
}
export interface SnackBarI {
  information: string
  success: string
}
export interface BadgesI {
  action: string
  special: string
}
export interface MenuItemI {
  background: string
  text: string
  active: {
    background: string
    text: string
  }
  hover: {
    background: string
  }
}
export interface TableListI {
  backgroundHeader: string
  headerText: string
  listItemBackground: string
  hover: {
    background: string
  }
}
export interface PaginationI {
  active: {
    background: string
    border: string
    text: string
  }
  hover: {
    background: string
  }
}
export interface PanelI {
  expansionIcon: string
  background: string
  hover: string
  text: {
    primary: string
  }
}
export interface ShadeI {
  answerOption: {
    primary: string
  }
  tabBody: string
  note: string
  panelCard: string
  panelCardIe: string
  modal: string
}
export interface MuiAccordionI {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: string
    lineHeight: number | string
  }
}
interface BackgroundColorI {
  backgroundColor: string
}
export interface MuiAlertI {
  filledSuccess: {
    backgroundColor: string
  }
  filledInfo: {
    backgroundColor: string
  }
  filledError: {
    backgroundColor: string
  }
  filledWarning: {
    backgroundColor: string
  }
}
export interface MuiAutocompleteI {
  root: {
    border: string
  }
}
export interface MUIDataTableI {
  paper: {
    width: number | string
    border: number | string
    borderRadius: number | string
  }
  liveAnnounce: {
    height: number | string
    width: number | string
  }
}
export interface MuiTableRowI {
  root: {
    '&.MuiTableRow-hover': {
      '&:hover': BackgroundColorI
    }
    '&:hover': BackgroundColorI
  }
  head: {
    '&:hover': BackgroundColorI
  }
}
export interface MUIDataTableBodyCellI {
  root: {
    wordBreak: string
  }
}
export interface MUIDataTableHeadCellI {
  root: {
    fontWeight: number | string
  }
  fixedHeader: BackgroundColorI
}
export interface MUIDataTableToolbarI {
  root: {
    padding: number | string
    borderBottom: number | string
  }
}
export interface MuiTableContainerI {
  root: {
    borderRadius: string
    border: string
  }
}
export interface MuiTableHeadI {
  root: {
    '& .MuiTableRow-root': {
      background: string
    }
  }
}
export interface MuiTableBodyI {
  root: {
    '& .MuiTableRow-root': {
      background: string
    }
  }
}
export interface MUIDataTableHeadRowI {
  root: {
    background: string
  }
}
export interface MuiTableI {
  root: {
    border: string
  }
}
export interface MuiDividerI {
  root: {
    color: string
  }
}
export interface MuiInputAdornmentI {
  root: { height: number | string }
  marginDense: { padding: number | string }
  positionEnd: {
    marginLeft: number | string
  }
}
export interface MuiListItemI {
  button: {
    '&:hover': BackgroundColorI
  }
}
export interface MuiMenuI {
  paper: {
    background: string
    color: string
    borderRadius: number | string
  }
}
// Palette
export interface Palette {
  border: BorderInterface
  cardData: CardDataI
  list: ListInterface
  badges: BadgesI
  buttons: ButtonsInterface
  icon: IconInterface
  loader: LoaderInterface
  answerOption: AnswerOptionInterface
}
export interface MuiTooltipI {
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: string
    color: string
    fontSize: number | string
    padding: number | string
  }
  arrow: {
    color: string
  }
}
export interface MuiTabI {
  textColorInherit: {
    minWidth: number | string
    color: string
    '&.Mui-selected': {
      color: string
    }
  }
}
export interface MuiChipI {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: string
    color: string
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: string
      color: string
    }
  }
  clickable: {
    '&:hover': BackgroundColorI
  }
  deleteIcon: {
    color: string
    transition: string
    borderRadius: string
    '&:hover': {
      color: string
      backgroundColor: string
      transition: string
    }
  }
}
export interface MuiCssBaselineI {
  '@global': {
    a: {
      color: string
    }
    p: {
      margin: number | string
    }
    body: {
      backgroundColor: string
      color: string
      fontFamily: string
      overflow: string
    }
    '*::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: number | string
    }
    '*::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
      background: string
      borderRadius: number | string
      '-webkit-box-shadow': string
    }
    '*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      outline: string
      backgroundColor: string
      borderRadius: number | string
      border: number | string
      '&:hover': BackgroundColorI
    }
    '*:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      backgroundColor: string
      borderColor: string
      borderRadius: number | string
    }
  }
}

export interface CurbsideOverrideI extends ComponentsOverrides {
  MuiAccordion: MuiAccordionI
  MuiAlert: MuiAlertI
  MuiAutocomplete: MuiAutocompleteI
  MUIDataTable: MUIDataTableI // not found in mui 5list
  MuiTableRow: MuiTableRowI
  MUIDataTableBodyCell: MUIDataTableBodyCellI // not found in mui 5list
  MuiTableHead: MuiTableHeadI
  MuiTableBody: MuiTableBodyI
  MuiTable: MuiTableI
  MuiDivider: MuiDividerI
  MuiInputAdornment: MuiInputAdornmentI
  MuiListItem: MuiListItemI
  MuiMenu: MuiMenuI
  MuiPaper: {
    root: {
      color: string
    }
  }
  MuiTooltip: MuiTooltipI
  MuiTab: MuiTabI
  MuiTabs: {
    indicator: {
      backgroundColor: string
    }
  }
  MuiChip: MuiChipI
  MuiCssBaseline
}
```

F2-> theme.ts

```
import { TypographyOptions } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createTypography'
import { PaletteOptions, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'

import {
  AnswerOption,
  BackgroundOptionsInterface,
  Badge,
  Border,
  Buttons,
  CawOverrides,
  ColoredOptionsInterface,
  CommonScale,
  ContentDivider,
  Gradient,
  GreyScale,
  Highlight,
  Icon,
  List,
  Loader,
  Menu,
  Modal,
  PaletteTypography,
  Panel,
  Shade,
  Tab,
  Table,
} from './types'

interface CawPaletteInterface extends PaletteOptions {
  answerOption: AnswerOption
  buttons: Buttons
  background: BackgroundOptionsInterface
  badge: Badge
  grey: GreyScale
  common: CommonScale
  border: Border
  contentDivider: ContentDivider
  gradient: Gradient
  highlight: Highlight
  icon: Icon
  loader: Loader
  list: List
  menu: Menu
  modal: Modal
  panel: Panel
  tab: Tab
  table: Table
  typography: PaletteTypography
  type: string
}

interface CawTypography extends TypographyOptions {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  quinary: string
  highlight: string
  active: string
  dark: string
  light: string
  greenHighlight: string
  checkboxPrimary: string
  orderCheckBoxPrimary: string
  questionLabel: string
  nodeEdgeIconPrimary: string
  action: string
  white: string
  black: string
  grey3: string
  grey4: string
  grey5: string
  grey6: string
  grey7: string
  grey11: string
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Theme {
    palette: CawPaletteInterface
  }
  interface TypeBackground {
    colored: ColoredOptionsInterface
  }

  interface BackgroundOptionsInterface extends TypeBackground {
    colored: ColoredOptionsInterface
  }

  interface CawTypography extends TypographyOptions {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
    tertiary: string
    quaternary: string
    quinary: string
    highlight: string
    active: string
    light: string
    greenHighlight: string
    nodeEdgeIconPrimary: string
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles/createTypography' {
  interface TypographyOptions {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
    tertiary: string
    quaternary: string
    quinary: string
    highlight: string
    active: string
    dark: string
    light: string
    greenHighlight: string
    checkboxPrimary: string
    orderCheckBoxPrimary: string
    questionLabel: string
    nodeEdgeIconPrimary: string
    action: string
    white: string
    black: string
    grey3: string
    grey4: string
    grey5: string
    grey6: string
    grey7: string
    grey11: string
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material' {
  interface Color {
    grey0: string
    grey1: string
    grey2: string
    grey3: string
    grey4: string
    grey5: string
    grey6: string
    grey7: string
    grey8: string
    grey9: string
    grey10: string
    grey11: string
    grey12: string
  }
  interface TypeBackground {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
    tertiary: string
    quaternary: string
    important: string
    activeVitalTimeOptions: string
  }
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Theme {
    palette: CawPaletteInterface
    typography: CawTypography
    shade?: Shade
    overrides?: CawOverrides
  }

  interface ThemeOptions {
    shade?: Shade
    overrides?: CawOverrides
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    answerOption: AnswerOption
    buttons: Buttons
    badge: Badge
    border: Border
    contentDivider: ContentDivider
    gradient: Gradient
    highlight: Highlight
    icon: Icon
    loader: Loader
    list: List
    menu: Menu
    modal: Modal
    panel: Panel
    tab: Tab
    table: Table
    typography: PaletteTypography
    type: string
  }
}

export interface CurbsideExtendedMuiFiveTheme extends Theme {
  palette: CawPaletteInterface
  typography: CawTypography
  shade?: Shade
  overrides?: CawOverrides
}
```

F2 -> types.ts

```
import { ComponentsOverrides } from '@mui/material'
import { TypeBackground } from '@mui/material/styles/createPalette'

export interface ColoredOptionsInterface {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  important: string
  activeVitalTimeOptions: string
}

export interface BackgroundOptionsInterface extends TypeBackground {
  colored: ColoredOptionsInterface
}

export interface AnswerOption {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  active: string
  tertiary: string
  border: string
  text: string
}

export interface Buttons {
  gradient: string
  icon: string
}

export interface Badge {
  orderCounterBG: string
  los: string
}

export interface Border {
  activeFaded: string
}

export interface ContentDivider {
  primary: string
  tertiary: string
}

export interface Gradient {
  primary: string
}

export interface Highlight {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  quinary: string
}

export interface Icon {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  background: {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
  }
  light: {
    hover: string
  }
}

export interface Loader {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
}

export interface List {
  highlight: string
  background: {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
    tertiary: string
    homeLabel: string
    homeList: string
  }
  text: {
    primary: string
  }
}

export interface Menu {
  footerMenuBackground: string
}

export interface Modal {
  primary: string
  header: string
  headerText: string
  background: {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
  }
  checkbox: {
    primary: string
    secondary: string
  }
}

export interface Panel {
  expansionIcon: string
  background: string
  hover: string
  text: {
    primary: string
  }
}

export interface Tab {
  header: {
    active: string
  }
  bodyBackground: {
    primary: string
  }
}

export interface Table {
  header: string
  primary: string
}

export interface GreyScale {
  grey0: string
  grey1: string
  grey2: string
  grey3: string
  grey4: string
  grey5: string
  grey6: string
  grey7: string
  grey8: string
  grey9: string
  grey10: string
  grey11: string
  grey12: string
}

export interface CommonScale {
  white: string
  black: string
}

export interface Typography {
  dark: string
  fontFamilty: string
  checkboxPrimary: string
  orderCheckBoxPrimary: string
  questionLabel: string
  action: string
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  quinary: string
  highlight: string
  active: string
  light: string
  greenHighlight: string
  nodeEdgeIconPrimary: string
  white: string
  black: string
  grey3: string
  grey4: string
  grey5: string
  grey6: string
  grey7: string
  grey11: string
}

export interface PaletteTypography {
  primary: string
  secondary: string
  tertiary: string
  quaternary: string
  quinary: string
  highlight: string
  active: string
  light: string
  greenHighlight: string
  nodeEdgeIconPrimary: string
}

export interface Shade {
  answerOption: {
    primary: string
  }
  tabBody: string
  note: string
  panelCard: string
  panelCardIe: string
  modal: string
}

interface MuiTabOverrides {
  textColorPrimary: {
    color: string
  }
}

interface MuiChipOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
    backgroundColor: string
    fontWeight: number
  }
  outlined: {
    color: string
    border: string
  }
  clickable: {
    '&:hover, &:focus': {
      backgroundColor: string
    }
  }
}
interface MuiAccordianOverrides {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: string
    lineHeight: string
  }
}

interface MuiRadioStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
  }
  colorSecondary: {
    color: string
  }
}

interface MuiButtonStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
    '&:hover': {
      color: string
    }
  }
  contained: {
    color: string
    '&:hover': {
      color: string
    }
  }
}

interface MuiInputStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
    backgroundColor: string
    '&:hover': {
      background: string
    }
    '&.Mui-focused': {
      backgroundColor: string
    }
    '& ::-webkit-input-placeholder': {
      color: string
      opacity: number
    }
  }
}

interface MuiInputBaseStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
    backgroundColor: string
    '&:hover': {
      background: string
    }
    '&.Mui-focused': {
      backgroundColor: string
    }
    '& ::-webkit-input-placeholder': {
      color: string
      opacity: number
    }
  }
}

interface MuiOutlinedInputStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: string
    }
    '&$disabled .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: string
    }
  }
  notchedOutline: {
    border: string
    borderColor: string
    borderRadius: string
    '&:active': {
      border: string
    }
  }
}

interface MuiSvgIconStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: string
      boxShadow: string
    }
  }
}

interface MuiTypographyStyleOverrides {
  caption: {
    fontSize: string
    fontWeight: string
    lineHeight: string
    letterSpacing: string
  }
  h4: {
    fontFamily: string
    fontWeight: string
    color: string
  }
  h5: {
    fontFamily: string
    fontWeight: string
    color: string
  }
}

interface MuiListItemStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    cursor: string
    color: string
    borderRadius: string
    margin: string
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: string
    }
    '&.Mui-selected': {
      backgroundColor: string
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: string
      }
    }
  }
  button: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: string
    }
  }
}

interface MuiListItemIconStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
  }
}

interface MuiMenuStyleOverrides {
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: string
  }
}

interface MuiPaperStyleOverrides {
  root: {
    color: string
    backgroundColor: string
  }
}

interface MuiPopoverStyleOverrides {
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: string
  }
}

export interface CawOverrides extends ComponentsOverrides {
  MuiTab: MuiTabOverrides
  MuiChip: MuiChipOverrides
  MuiAccordion: MuiAccordianOverrides
  MuiRadio: MuiRadioStyleOverrides
  MuiButton: MuiButtonStyleOverrides
  MuiInput: MuiInputStyleOverrides
  MuiInputBase: MuiInputBaseStyleOverrides
  MuiOutlinedInput: MuiOutlinedInputStyleOverrides
  MuiSvgIcon: MuiSvgIconStyleOverrides
  MuiTypography: MuiTypographyStyleOverrides
  MuiListItem: MuiListItemStyleOverrides
  MuiListItemIcon: MuiListItemIconStyleOverrides
  MuiMenu: MuiMenuStyleOverrides
  MuiPaper: MuiPaperStyleOverrides
  MuiPopover: MuiPopoverStyleOverrides
  MuiCssBaseline
}
```